# Objective-C objects are nil while debugging static library

Tags: objective-c, xcode, debugging, static-libraries

I have created a custom static library in iOS .

The Project that uses the static library and the static library  Project reside in the same workspace. I set it up this way, because it helps me to debug using breakpoints.

When I debug, all the objective-C objects are nil.

How do I view their values?

Comment: How are you debugging? What's the optimisation level of your static library target?

Comment: Thanks MacMade. The problem occurred because the static library was in release mode.

Answer (score 0):

Even though the application's scheme was in Debug mode, the library was built in Release mode using shell script for creating fat static library. This was the reason for the problem.

When I customised the shell script to throw the relevant fat static library based on the scheme of the Static library Project, this problem did not occur.